# Focus not highlighting anchor link on tab

Tags: css, focus, anchor

All anchor links except for one are getting background color changed on focus, except for one.

HTML

`<a id="login-as-guest">Cancel and browse as guest</a>`

CSS

`#login-as-guest a:focus{
    background-color: yellow;
}`

Any ideas?

Comment: should that not be `a#login-as-guest:focus` ?

Comment: @PeterVR, no that doesn't work.

Comment: can you set up an example in jsfiddle? I do not entirely understand what you are after...

Comment: When you focus on the textbox, and then hit the tab key, the focus(background color) of the text "Cancel and browse as guest" should be highlighted yellow.

http://jsfiddle.net/VKvBy/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To use focus you need to assign a tabindex to the element as it is not an input. Otherwise you could use `active`. Also your code is not correct. Currently it is looking for an `a` element within an element with that `ID`.

The correct way would be

```
a#login-as-guest:focus{ background-color: yellow; }
```

Both ways:
DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/t2hbS/

Comment: the `tabindex="0"` was the key, apparently. Didn't need to move the `a` tag though. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt: Without moving the `a`, it works for all a tags that are child of element with `id="login-as-guest"`. If your original style works, it is just because the browser is nice to you.

Comment: In my case the anchor wasn't getting the focus because it didn't have an href attribute, as I was creating it from javascript and using the onclick... so I didn't have that href...

Answer (score 12):

An anchor tag without a href attribute can not receive focus (at least in Chrome, but I think it is standard behaviour). Also you selector is incorrect, you are trying to select an `a` that is a descendant of `#login-as-guest`. The selector should be `a#login-as-guest:focus`, which will select a `a` with an id of `#login-as-guest` that has focus.

Have a look at the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VKvBy/1/

Comment: Thanks. I had mat-button anchors that used to pick up focus due to tabbing, but stopped... this answer helped me to realize that I didn't have hrefs in them.  Adding href="#" to each one solved the issue.